# How to use backspace in UnetStack Shell?

Tags: unetstack

Whenever I use backspace in Unet shell the cursor moves forward instead of erasing the line.Is there some other way to use backspace in unet shell ?

Comment: That is strange -- the backspace should work exactly as in any terminal/shell. What browser and OS are you on?

Comment: Possible bug. Tracked here: https://github.com/org-arl/fjage/issues/166

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS , I have tested on both Chrome : Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit) and firefox : 84.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug fixed by [PR 176](https://github.com/org-arl/fjage/pull/176). Will be part of fjåge release 1.9.0, but available today from the `dev` branch of fjåge, if you need it.